# Most readable way to get only surname of person in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I just want to get the surname of the people in my database.
If I have the name 'John Mckain William', I want 'Mckain William'.
The way I found to do this is with this solution:

```
RIGHT(person.name, length(person.name) - (length(split_part(person.name, ' ', 1)) + 1))
```

That way, I get the length of the entire string, subtract the length from the first name, get the length of the surname -1 (so as not to have a space as the first letter) and 'cut' the string with 'RIGHT Function'. But it is not very readable and it is ugly. Is there a better and more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `regexp_matches`:

```sql
(regexp_matches(name, '[^\s]+\s(.+)'))[1]
```

The regex skips a series of non-whitespace characters, then skips whitespaces and then captures whatever remains, i.e. the surname as is. The expression returns the first capture. If `name` contains no surname then the expression yields `null`.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(name, '\s+'))[2:], ' ')
```

This first converts the name into an array with one element for each word. Then it takes everything starting with the second element and converts the array back to a string.